# Django : How to hide a variable in a template

Tags: django, variables, templates

I have a template with a tree
Ceramic Composite Metals general
I want to hide general

I wrote

```
{% for category in object_list %}

{% if category != "general" %}

<li class="closed"><span class="folder"><a >{{ category }}</a></span></li>

{% endif %}
```

it does not work

What is the error

Comment: What is a `category`? Is it just a string?

Comment: No, It is a variable

Comment: category.name != "general" ??? what is category look like?

Comment: It is also a character string

Comment: what is your field name for general?

Comment: I have a template with a file tree with the names Ceramic Composite ...

Comment: The field name is 'general' I use it in other parts of the program and I do not want to see 'general' in this page

Comment: As three people have now asked, please show exactly what `category` is and where it comes from. Where is it defined? Since it is coming from `object_list`, which is presumably a list in a ListView, that implies `category` is a model, not a string. **Please show the model definition**.

Comment: sorry, Yes, I have a class Category

Comment: class Category(models.Model):                                                            name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the template, `{{ category }}` is interpreted as `Category.__str__()` and a string is displayed.

But in `{% if category != "general" %}`, `category` is an object that will always be different to the String `"general"`. What you want to do is: `{% if category.name != "general" %}`

Also, note that if you don't use categories named `"general"` in this template, you should filter them out when querying the db. It will be more efficient.